# How to filter some repository URL list according tags via Azure Devops API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Thanks for your attention.I am a new Azure Devops API user.

Now,I want to filter some repo url with a same tag.

According the api rule base on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated-tags/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags/{objectId}?api-version=7.0
```

I can get {organization},{project},{repositoryId}, but I haven't find the API to get the tag's id:{objectId}.

```
objectId    path    True    string   ObjectId (Sha1Id) of tag to get.
```

Then I want to create a new tag with the output result to get the tag id for a workaround,base on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated-tags/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags?api-version=7.0
```

However,there is no parameter to define the tag name.

Question: Is there any way to get the ADO repo's tag id with command if i have the tag name?

OR:
Is there any way to filter all repo URL with the same tag name via command?

Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Is there any way to get the ADO repo's tag id with command
> if i have the tag name?

You can use [Refs – List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#refs_tags)  to get tag objectid.

Find the tag here:

[image]

Comment: It seems i make some mistake.  The tag record a commit status, likes a snapshot for a commit version. There are difference with AURE Portal resource's tag.